# How I can create sshkey in Windows 8 through puttygen.exe?

Tags: node.js, debugging

"Please add an SSH key before provisioning a machine".

I am trying to create ssh keys from puttygen.exe in windows. I am unable to find puttygen.exe in Win8 rp.

Can someone help me how I can create ssh keys in windows. I want to create it for https://no.de/sshkeys.

Comment: http://theillustratednetwork.mvps.org/Ssh/copSSH-WinSCP-KeyPair.html

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla pls make your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PuTTYgen is automatically installed on the client PC when WinSCP is installed or it can be downloaded from the [PuTTY site](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

On the client PC go to `Start | Run` and run the `C:\Program Files\WinSCP\PuTTYgen\puttygen.exe` program from the command line.

Select `SSH-2 RSA and 4096 bits`. Click on the Generate key.

Enter an appropriate/descriptive Key comment, enter a strong pass phrase in the Key passphrase window then reenter the pass phrase in the Confirm the passphrase window.

Good pass phrases are **10-30 characters long, are not simple sentences** or otherwise easily guessable (English prose has only 1-2 bits of entropy per character, and provides very bad pass phrases), and contain a mix of upper and lowercase letters, numbers, and non-alphanumeric characters.

> Do NOT forget the pass phrase. Lost pass phrases can NOT BE RECOVERED.

Copy the text generated into no.de ssh key console.

Hope this helps