# GUI public ssh key generator

Tags: git, user-interface, ssh-keys, tortoisegit

Is there any GUI tool for non tech-savvy users that are not willing to use CLI allowing them to generate public rsa key?
(except the [putty method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049510/how-i-can-create-sshkey-in-windows-8-through-puttygen-exe))

This is the common case when one of the project members needs to get access to the repo (e.g. via TortoiseGit, but's hard to force them to generate the key to give them the access).

Comment: What's wrong with PuttyGEN? (Other GUI ssh clients probably have an equivalent thing too, so it's important to know why you reject this option).

Answer (score 1):

There is something called [REBEX](http://www.rebex.net/sample/key-generation/default.aspx) but it's almost identical to [PuTTYgen](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/puttygen.exe)

Answer (score 1):

[GitExtensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) is has a reasonably simple UI for generating keys. In general this seems a more useful UI than Tortoise Git for Windows users. It is found on the remotes menu. Forcing them is simple. If the remote server requires keys (use gitolite with [GitLab](http://gitlab.org/) to provide a web based access control) then users don't get a choice. We find that with gitlab linked to the local ActiveDirectory users can create new projects and add their keys with a pretty minimal guide document.